# Render html with node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, mean

I am really new to the whole MEAN-stack and are trying to create an application on openshift but are unable to render a new page.

I just keep getting this error and can't solve it with anything I've googled.

***My Error: Failed to lookup view "/register" in public directory***

It works completely fine to render the index page with app.get('/', func()) in server.js and tried to to the exact same thing with app.get('/register). I used to have the same problem with '/' at first but solved it using app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

Both index.html and register.html are located in the public directory.

These are extracts of my code:

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="LoginController" >
        <h1>Logg in</h1>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="ID"/>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
        <button class="btn">Logga in</button>
        <button ng-click="open()" class="btn">Register User</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

**logincontroller**

```
function LoginController($scope, $http) {
console.log("Hello from Login");

    $scope.open = function () {
        console.log('open i login.js');
        $http.get('/register')
    };
};
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var fs      = require('fs');
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var jade = require('jade')

var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.get('/env',function(req, res){
    res.json(process.env);
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('/index', {});
});

app.get('/register', function (req, res) {
    res.render('/register');
});

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.

1) Don't use a slash for the 'register' file.  This is a file in the `/public` folder, not a folder or route.

```
app.get('/register', function (req, res) {
    res.render('register');
});
```

2) You have set `jade` as your rendering engine.  This means you will be serving `.jade` files.  Your public folder should have `index.jade`.  And it should look like this:

```
html
  body(ng-app='')
    .container(ng-controller='LoginController')
      h1 Logg in
      input.form-control(placeholder='ID')
      input.form-control(placeholder='Password')
      button.btn Logga in
      button.btn(ng-click='open()') Register User
```

A couple of notes:

- Jade is a HTML templating engine, it's relatively straight forward, see http://jade-lang.com/tutorial/.
- There is express-generator which will give you an example app, it's an excellent starting point: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html
- By the way, there is also an HTML-2-Jade converter, I find this helpful sometimes: http://html2jade.org/